# don't want inner joins on django models

Tags: django, django-models, inner-join

i've migrated an existing database that i would like to work with django. i have the following models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'DEVICES'
        managed=False
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=22, db_column='DEVICE_ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='DEVICE_NAME')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column='STATUS')

class DevicePort(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'DEVICE_PORT'
        managed=False
    id = models.CharField( primary_key=True, max_length=22, db_column='DEVICE_PORT_ID')
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, db_column='DEVICE_ID')
    type = models.CharField( max_length=22, db_column='PORT_TYPE_ID')
    port_num = models.CharField( max_length=30, db_column='DEVICE_PORT_NUM')

class IP(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'IP_NODE'
        managed=False
    ip_address = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15, db_column='IP_NODE_NO')
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='IP_HOST')
    port = models.OneToOneField(DevicePort, db_column='DEVICE_PORT_ID')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='IP_NODE_STATUS')
```

i want a list of `Devices` and their relational `IP.ip_address` and `IP.hostname`s. In SQL, i would do something like:

```
SELECT UNIQUE
    d.device_name device
FROM 
    IP_NODE c, 
    DEVICES d, 
    DEVICE_PORT e
WHERE
    c.ip_node_no = b.ip_node_no 
  AND c.device_port_id = e.device_port_id 
  AND e.device_id = d.device_id 
  AND d.device_name LIKE 'something';
```

How do i do this with my django models?

Comment: Okay, amuse me. *Why* don't you want it to use an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: You can always execute your own SQL statements instead of letting the ORM dictate the statement used: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 1):

So instead of an inner join you want...and implicit join?  Is there something I'm missing here because an implicit join is slower than an explicit one most all cases.

[http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/explicit-JOIN-faster-than-implicit-td1920335.html][1]

I can't see any reason you would want to do this, but as stated above you can certainty get this by writing your own queries with raw, or even connection.cursor.  Maybe even could pull it off with extra(tables=[...]), though I'm not positive as I've never used tables like this.

Comment: thanks for the link; quite interesting... anyway, i guess i should rephrase the question a little: my issue is that i want distinct `Device`s and their relevant `IP`s - as `Device` doesn't have any references to `DevicePort` nor `IP`, i'm not sure how to proceed. cheers,

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about. The relation between `Device` and `DevicePort` is *very* clear in your code.